# Auto-correlation callback function issue - loadrunner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I'm working in new application written in *Siebel 8.1*, issue appears when I'm trying to replay script and I can't handle that.

Replay Output:

> Error -27086: Auto-correlation callback function
>   "flCorrelationCallbackParseWebPage" failed (rc=1) for parameter
>   "Siebel_Parse_Web_Page40"

```
web_reg_save_param("Siebel_Parse_Web_Page40", 
    "LB/IC=", 
    "RB/IC=", 
    "Ord=1", 
    "Search=Body", 
    "RelFrameId=1", 
    "AutoCorrelationFunction=flCorrelationCallbackParseWebPage", 
    "AutoCorrelationDll=LrwiSiebelCorrelationWrapper", 
    LAST);
```

I have done all steps for prepare record options from: http://software-qe.blogspot.se/2008/01/siebel-7x-record-and-replay-for.html

I'm using Loadrunner 11.52 (Siebel Web protocol), IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If auto(magical)correlation does not work then use manual correlation.

Record twice with same data: Compare.   You will find session, state and time data.

Change the credentials: Re-record.  Compare.  You will find credential related correlation

Change the business record but keep the same business process.  Re-Record.  You will find the business related correlation.

Do not expect autocorrelation to provide a magical working script.  You have about a 0.0001% chance of that happening without LoadRunner script development intervenetion.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using the autocorrelation library for quite a few years on my team and we see this a lot. Unfortunately, it's not an easy problem to diagnose.

First I would check your test results and your VUser log to see if something happened before the autocorrelation failed.  (Make sure your logging is set to parameter substitution in runtime settings).

Check your parameter files for extra spaces, commas, etc. Sometimes I've seen that error right after it rejects something about your parameter file.

Worst case scenario, your script is corrupted and you'll have to start over. We've gotten in the habit of making frequent backups of our scripts just because of this issue. Usually, we'll be able to start from our backup and continue or create a new script and paste the old code in. Autocorrelation error "magically" goes away with the same code in a new script.